# Windows NTFS : How to reset security easily?

Tags: windows, security, ntfs

(My English can be strange ..)

I have one external HDD formated by NTFS. I use this HDD as my data storage.

When I reinstall windows, external HDD's security settings seem to remain, so I must have administrator privileges to access external HDD. Sometimes, I must reset security settings of EACH FILE!

I tried to reset HDD's security setting, but It takes too long time;;

How do I reset HDD's security easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to give the Everyone group Full Control permissions to the root of the drive, then force the permissions to inherit to all subfolders.

Comment: setting the root of the drive: Doesn't it takes so much time? My HDD  contains lots of files and folders.. Isn't there any other way? T.T

Comment: Unfortunately, no, unless all files/subfolders are configured to inherit from the parent folder. NTFS permissions are per file. However, you only need to do this once, and never again.